# HDFS error: target already exists

Tags: hadoop

I am very new to Hadoop. When I try to execute this command it says that the target already exists. How do I remove this file from hadoop? Is that the same as removing the target?

```
me$ hdfs -copyFromLocal myfile.txt input/myfile.txt

copyFromLocal: Target input/myfile.txt already exists
```

Comment: It is complaining that input/myfile.txt exists already, can you try removing the file and execute the command again.

Comment: @RameshK how do I remove the file in the hadoop system?

Answer (score 11):

You don't have to remove the file first and then copy the new one. You can do it in one step by using the `-f` option with `-copyFromLocal`

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal -f myfile.txt input/myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the file from your HDFS, then you'd do:

```
$ hadoop dfs -rm <filePath>
```

In your case, you need to:

```
$ hadoop dfs -rm input/myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This command deletes recursively and allows you to delete directories.

```
hadoop dfs -rmr <aDirectory>
```

It is like `rm -rf aDirectory` in `linux`

Answer (score 0):

For Mapreduce 2.x you want to to use:

```
hadoop fs -rm /path/to/filename
```

The most common options for this are to add the -r flag if you want to delete an entire directory (like the results of an MR). Note that -rmr is deprecated.

```
hadoop fs -rm -r /path/to/files
```

You can add the -skipTrash flag if you're deleting a large set of files and don't want them sitting around until trash collection occurs.

```
hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash /path/to/files
```